# G Sheets cond column-wide formatting IF the date is in next 3 days AND it is Monday

Tags: google-sheets

| A header | B header | C header |
| --- | --- | --- |
| First | 01.01.2000 | something |
| Second | 02.01.2000 | something |

I have a sheet with B column filled with dates.
I have 4 conditional formattings: today, tomorrow and "overmorrow" dates.
The fourth condition is the following:

Mark the cell IF its date is today()+3 AND its weekday is Monday.
The simple options "date is exactly" works for "today()+2". But it declines to works with =and() formula. It should get the date type, not a boolean.

As for the formula option, I cannot invent the right formula. This doesn't work:

=and(today()+2,weekday()=2) - I believe that, when you select a non-simple option (not like date -> is exactly) it should take the real arguments, and should not contain empty function calls like weekday().

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y7gEW.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use this custom formula: `=AND(B1=today()+2,weekday(B1)=2)`

### Sample:

**Custom formula:** `=AND(B1=today()+3,weekday(B1)=2)`

> Note: I used `today()+3` temporarily just to show that the conditional formatting is working since my current day is friday.

[image]

Comment: Please let me know if you encountered an issue

Comment: I am just a bit confused about B1. Why should I address only one cell? How would it work for the whole column?..
I am not an experienced sheets user so far.

Comment: Yes, the Sheets keep telling me that the formula is "invalid".

Comment: It agrees with AND(B1=today()+3,weekday(B1)=2) but that doesn't work.
You variant looks more correct but the Sheets GUI doesn't even accept it.

Comment: the one cell used in the formula will act as the start cell. Then it will automatically iterate the current cell based on the range that you provided. So for example your range selected is `B1:B`, it will iterate the start cell within the range provided. But if you used the range `B1:C` the start cell will also adjust/check column C when iterating like checking B1, C1, B2, C2 so on... of course you can use absolute reference ($B1) if you don't want to iterate the column C when you use the range `B1:C`

Comment: can you share a sample sheet? [Share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383)

Comment: I think you missed to include `=` it should be `=AND(B1=today()+3,weekday(B1)=2) `

Comment: Sorry! My fault: the delimiter between arguments should be (in my case) a semicolon, not a comma. I believe this is tweaked somewhere in preferences. It works now. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that